# PHPMailer with attachment

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

So, i'm having problem with this code.
It's a form where it get the data and this is the phpmailer fragment, where i get the error Could not acess file

```
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$message= $_REQUEST['message'];
$message= "--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;
$message= "Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'" . PHP_EOL;
$message= "--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;
$tapete=$_REQUEST['tapete'];
$medidas=$_REQUEST['medidas'];
$cliente=$_REQUEST['cliente'];
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "mucapapipa.br@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "----";
$mail->Subject   = 'Formulário FacilityCom';
$mail->setFrom = ('mucapapipa.br@gmail.com');
$mail->Body      = 'Tipo e marca: $tapete \nMedidas: $medidas \nCliente:         $cliente\n $from';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddAttachment($file['tmp_name'], $file['name']);
$mail->Send();`
```

Comment: `$file` isn't defined. (maybe you're looking for [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)?)

Comment: Wow, thanks @HPierce How do i define this var exactly? Also, transform it in answer please, so i can give you upvote.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong here.

Don't mess with boundaries - PHPMailer does all that for you.

`$mail->setFrom = ('mucapapipa.br@gmail.com')` should be `$mail->setFrom('mucapapipa.br@gmail.com')`.

It would help if you based your code on [the file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) as that shows how to handle file uploads correctly.

Comment: ok, i did it, but, but i'm still having problems, the mail don't get to my inbox.

Comment: From the debug output, can you see that it was sent successfully?

Comment: Using chrome console? Nothing.

Comment: Chrome console has nothing to do with this! You should be seeing debug output in your web page or your terminal.

Comment: I used, however, i can't.

Comment: If you're not seeing any debug outut when you have `SMTPDebug = 2`, you have a general problem with the way you're running your script, so it's probaby not running at all.